Search for co-authoring of crypto papers
It has happen to me many times, as I'm not a full time researcher,  that I have an innovative crypto idea but lack the time to write a paper or lack the knowledge to do the hard-work of proving my assertions.
It would be great if there would be place in the Cryptography stackexchange site to post ideas and search for co-authors who want to write the paper together.
Does this place already exist?

I fear that this fits less the question-and-answer format of Stack Exchange.

The question might fit better if it were in the form of a question :).  Something like "what is the best way to find coauthors for crypto papers?"

To be honest, I don't encourage this.  I view this as analogous to saying "I have a great idea for a startup, my idea is so brilliant it's going to be the next Facebook, now I'd just like to hire a few programmers to build it for me".  In startups, good ideas are a dime a dozen; the hard work of executing on the idea is the heart of it.  In many crypto papers, the hard work of proving your assertions is the heart of it.
If you think you have an innovative crypto idea, you could post it here for review, and you might get some review.  But I would go into it with humility and low expectations.

Yes, but it would be nice to have some resources for cryptographers to 'get things done' as Joel Spolsky is fond of saying. I think that's the point of the Q&A forums: to help people who need specific information to do their work. 
You could trivially add your interest in writing papers in your profile. 
In your user profile, on the info tab, the big grey box to the right of 'Registered User' allows you to write freeform notes. 
Put something like:
'Interested in co-authorship of topics in parallelization of encryption and signal detection.'
